# Changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH broke my system

Tags: apt, bash, matlab

I'm writing this from my phone because I can't get my laptop to boot, so I'll do my best, sorry for the poor formatting. I use Lubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

I did something I shouldn't have apparently. I was trying to make Matlab work, so I ran a few bash lines as seen somewhere on the internet. The commands (as seen in `~/.bash_history`) were:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.028 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64 MATLAB -desktop
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.028 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64 MATLAB -desktop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64/"
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After doing this, stuff stopped working so I rebooted. Now I can't even start Lubuntu desktop, nor login. After some loading when booting, it shows a message

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
```

and it just does nothing, only the blinking cursor in the next line.

I can only access root terminal from "advanced options for Lubuntu" in grub menu, from where I have been executing lots of random, desperate, nonsense commands regarding this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` thing, but it's no good.

If I run `echo &LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it returns a void string and then goes back to prompt.

I can't run `apt` or anything related. For example, if I try to run `sudo apt update` I get this scary error:

```
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
```

So `add-apt-repository` and such are not available.

I really need some help. Thanks so much in advance.

PS: Sorry for not providing more information, I can't think of what would be helpful, I'll be happy to edit the question with any data you request.

*EDIT0*:
executing `realpath /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` in recovery mode root terminal gives:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
```

*EDIT1*:
As I said, I ran lots of random and desperate commands from the recovery mode terminal. I've typed some of them as seen in `/root/.bash_history` file

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
reboot
cat /home/user/.bash_history
reboot
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
reboot
sudo ldconfig
reboot
dpkg-reconfigure
dpkg-reconfigure dbus
reboot
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
reboot
export 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
reboot
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
reboot
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
reboot
-static-libstdc++
reboot
```

*EDIT2*:
To see which .so files I actually have, I ran `ls /usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu | grep libstdc++` and returns

```
libstdc++.so.6
libstsc++.so.6.0.28
```

*EDIT3:*
Note that my system is in spanish, so my translation might not be exactly as it would be shown for any of you.

the output of `dpkg -C libstdc++` is

```
The packages listed below have been unpacked but not yet configured. They must be configured using "dpkg --configure" or the "Configure" option in dselect so they work.
libstdc++6:amd64       GNU standard C++ Library v3
```

Next, the output of `dpkg --configure stdc++6` is

```
dpkg: error while processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--configure)
   the package libstdc++6:amd64 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 can not be configured because libstdc++6:i386 is in a different version (12-20220319-1ubuntu1)
Found errors while processing:
    libstdc++6:amd64
```

Comment: AFAIK `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty by default, and simply running those commands in a terminal doesn't make persistent changes anyhow. Are you sure those are the only commands you ran?

Comment: I typed the commands as seen in the `~/.bash_history` file. I ran a few others trying to make matlab work. Give me a sec and I will edit the question

Comment: there, added the first three

Comment: So what does `realpath /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` return? is it resolved to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30` (correct) or to something like `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.028` ?

Comment: from reading your question, it's apparently wrong. Just added an edit so you can see it.

Comment: Is the newer .so file present (i.e. only the symlink is wrong)? Does `dpkg -C libstdc++6` provide any information?

Comment: probably not. I used `ls` and got what you can see in *EDIT2*.

Comment: `dpkg -C stdc++6` gives what you see in *EDIT3*

Comment: Hmm... so you seem to have somehow force-installed a much older version of the package (apparently from the 20.04 Focal Fossa repository)

Comment: damn, I do not know when or how I was able to do that... should I get the correct file and place it where it belongs? do I also need to delete the old one (maybe just rename it will do)?

Comment: tbh I don't know the safest way to proceed at this point - possibly to use `dpkg` (which doesn't seem to depend on `libstdc++`) to install the correct jammy package?